# Error "Input string was not in a correct format" with sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssms

I'm having trouble with getting an int value from my sql data base:

```
if(Convert.ToDouble(dbh.getInfo("firstTime", username))==1)
```

and I also tried:

```
if((int)dbh.getInfo("firstTime", username)==1)
```

and this is the getInfo function:

```
public object getInfo(string infoReq, string username)
        {
            string query = "select (@infoReq) from AccountDB where username like @username";
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@infoReq", infoReq);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
                    con.Open();
                    return cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){

            }
            return MessageBox.Show("Please check your fields");
        }
```

`dbh` is a `DBHandler` type which that is where that function is from of course

in the sql data base, the DataType of that `@infoReq` for this matter is a bit (in sql: `[firstTime] BIT NOT NULL`)

what is the problem with my code?

Comment: Did you debug your code? What exact value is being returned from the `getInfo` method? Are you seeing the message box `Please check your fields` ? You can not use parameter for the columns in Select statement.

Comment: I’m not sure your query makes any sense.  You are passing @infoReq as a string and then just returning it, then trying to convert it to a scalar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public object getInfo(string infoReq, string username)
{
    string query = "select @infoReq from AccountDB where username like '%@username%'";
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@infoReq", infoReq);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
            con.Open();
            return cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){

    }
    return MessageBox.Show("Please check your fields");
}
```

Comment: can you shortly explain to me the purpose of the ```%```?
it worked

Comment: The % is the sql wildcard